# How to classify/ solve this PDE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I am searching how to solve the PDE below but I can not seem to find a decent example online. My major did not focus much in solving PDEs so I feel very deficient.

I know how to solve for the steady state - but I am wondering if I can solve the following analytically, not numerically.

\begin{gather*}
\frac{\partial F(x, t)}{\partial t} = -g(x)F(x, t)
-A\frac{\partial F(x, t)}{\partial x}-B\frac{\partial^{2}F(x, t)}{\partial x^{2}} \\
\\
IC: F(x, 0) = 1
\end{gather*}

I thought about doing a Fourier transform but I end up with a convolution in freq space - and that would be hard to handle. I also know that this is an advection - diffusion - convection PDE but its not specific enough to return any nice Google searches.

Any suggestion or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

---

Follow up:

Consider Case 1, where function g(t) is only a function of time.

\begin{gather*}
g(t) :  = \frac{\alpha \left(\frac{t}{\beta }\right)^{\alpha -1}}{\beta } \\
\\
\frac{\partial F(x, t)}{\partial t} = -\left(\frac{\alpha \left(\frac{t}{\beta }\right)^{\alpha -1}}{\beta }\right)F(x, t) 
-A\frac{\partial F(x, t)}{\partial x}-B\frac{\partial^{2}F(x, t)}{\partial x^{2}}
\\
\\
\frac{\partial\tilde{F}(\omega , t)}{\partial t} = -\left(\frac{\alpha \left(\frac{t}{\beta }\right)^{\alpha -1}}{\beta }\right)\tilde{F}(\omega , t) 
-A(i2\pi \omega )\tilde{F}(\omega , t)+B(i2\pi \omega )^{2}\tilde{F}(\omega , t) \\
\\
\frac{\partial\tilde{F}(\omega , t)}{\partial t} = \left[-\left(\frac{\alpha \left(\frac{t}{\beta }\right)^{\alpha -1}}{\beta }\right)-A(i2\pi \omega )+B(i2\pi \omega )^{2}\right]\tilde{F}(\omega , t)
\\
\\
\mbox{The DE is of the form:} \\
y^{\prime}+ay = 0\mbox{ so when I solve I get: }\
\\
\\
\tilde{F}(\omega , t) =  
Ce^{\left(\frac{t}{\beta }\right)^{\alpha }+(A(i2\pi \omega )-B(i2\pi \omega )^{2})t} \\
\\
\mbox{-At this point I don't know how to apply the IC but if I assume C=1,} \\ \mbox{and take the inverse Fourier - I get the solution below - which looks good.} \\
\\
F(x, t) =  
\frac{e^{\left(\frac{t}{\beta }\right)^{\alpha }-\frac{(x+At)^{2}}{4Bt}}}{2\sqrt{\pi }\sqrt{Bt}}
\end{gather*}

When I plug in fixed values for all variables - I get the same values but opposite signs. This is somewhat good news but still I am a little confused.

---

Additional evidence

Here is the Mathematica ourput for the two derivative terms. Note the second derivative becomes positive.

A-Term:

```
In[2]:= FourierTransform[-A*D[f[t, x], x], x, w, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}]

Out[2]= -2 i A Pi w FourierTransform[f[t, x], x, w]
```

B-Term:

```
In[1]:= FourierTransform[-B*D[f[t, x], x, x], x, w, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}]

Out[1]= 4 B Pi^2 w^2 FourierTransform[f[t, x], x, w]
```

I kept everything consistent with Mathematica; therefore, I am confident my signs should be right.

I really hope someone can shed some light into this!!! I am almost depressed about it.

Comment: Have you tried [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of $F(x, t)$ for fixed $x$? That should convert the PDE into an ODE.

Comment: No, I have never used Laplace transforms.

Comment: By applying Laplace transform w.r.t. $t$, denoting the result of transform of $F(x, t)$ $\tilde{F}(x, s)$ and using the initial condition, the PDE becomes a linear second-order ODE with variable coefficients $s \tilde{F}(x, s) - 1 = -g(x) \tilde{F}(x, s) + A \frac{\partial \tilde{F}(x, s)}{\partial x} + B\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{F}(x, s)}{\partial x^2}$.

Comment: I see that and that's pretty cool. Thank you. I will make a follow up post if I can solve it this way.

Comment: Have you tried directly verifying your solution by plugging it in to the equation?

Comment: No I did not think of it - but I will do it now.

Comment: Ok - the solution is definitely wrong. I gave the same values to the variables in the first equation - and the LHS and the RHS are not the same. Where am I going wrong with my method?

Comment: Turns out the solution is not completely wrong. I do get same values but opposite sign for the LHS and RHS of the main equation. Any suggestions how to proceed forward?

Comment: After using the Fourier transform, you (accidentally, I presume) changed the sign of the term with $B$ in RHS. If the actual sign is the same as in the original equation, the result is $F(x, t) = \frac{C}{2 \sqrt{ -\pi B t}} \exp\left(\frac{(x - A t)^2}{4 B t} - (\frac{t}{\beta})^\alpha\right)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again. Unfortunately, I believe the signs are right. I did this with Mathematica. The B term is a second derivative so it changes the sign. I plugged in values for your version and it does not give the same values.

Comment: Doesn't $i^2$ in that term mean that the sign will change twice?

Comment: I added the Mathematica input/output above that shows my signs should be correct - or at least consistent with Mathematica.